# Repositories are not getting listed in Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, acr

I've Azure free Subscription and trying out ACR. I've pushed an image into the ACR. But the image is not getting listed in Repositories. Any leads are helpful. Attached the screenshot. Under montioring section, i can see one successfull image push. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

[image]

Tried pushing an image to the ACR which is success. But that image is not getting displayed under repositories.

Answer (score 0):

> Repositories are not getting listed in Azure Container Registry

Images are not showing up in the `Repositories` section in `Azure portal` after pushed to the `Azure Container Regist`. you can also check the images in repositories using azure cli command instead of checking in portal.

```
az acr repository list --name sriacr16 --output table
```

Sometimes, the `Azure portal` might not refresh automatically. Try refreshing the portal manually to see if the image appears.

I uploaded an image to `Azure Container Registry` using the below command.

```
docker push acrname.azurecr.io/demoimage/mywebapp:v2
```

[image]

Verify the images after uploaded to `ACR` using below command.

```
az acr repository list --name sriacr16 --output table
```

[image]

**Portal view:**

[image]

You can use the below command to check the image that you uploaded to `ACR` with a tag in the repository.

```
az acr manifest list sriacr16.azurecr.io/demoimage/mywebapp --output table
```

[image]

Comment: I'm able to see my image.

Comment: Result
--------
demo

Comment: If the images appear in the CLI, it seems that they have been uploaded to ACR successfully. Try refreshing the portal and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Add a role assignment for the user as contributor in your
container registry--> Access control(IAM)

THEN U CAN ABLE TO VIEW THE REPOS

Comment: STOP SCREAMING!